# How to build a local server to redirect an URL request via proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, alexa-skills-kit, simplehttpserver, ngrok

I'm new to HTTP world. Currently I want to develop a custom skill for Amazon Alexa and encountered this problem:

I want Alexa to stream an audio stream from a website (https://****.mp3) which cannot be accessed from US, and the only way to access it is via a proxy. Seems like there's no proxy option on Alexa API.
What software or platform can I use to create a local server to redirect the request from Alexa to https://****.mp3 via proxy?

Currently, I have gnrok running with SimpleHTTPServer so that once Alexa visit my local gnrok server ****.gnrok.io, it will be directed to https://****.mp3. But due to the lack of proxy, it cannot access the music. What should I do?

Thank you for any suggestions!!

Comment: You can't send an http redirect response back to a request which causes a client to choose to use a proxy.  However you can use proxy pac files to configure a client to use a particular proxy for a particular destination.

Comment: Hi Adrien, thank you for your reply! The issue is that I can't configure the client (Amazon Alexa) to use proxy. However, I want my local server to use a proxy to fetch the resource from audio stream for the client . What software platform should I look into? Thakns!

Comment: I'd be surprised if the Alexa didn't support proxy detection and auto-config.

Comment: Actually, because the music stream service ban the US IP, that's why I need a special proxy.